# Need informations about google API Key

Tags: android

I need help understanding Google API with android.
I've asked an external company to get access to their database and they said that I can get a free access. I'm realy happy at the moment but they said that they need the `API key details so they can provision it with Premier Free access. I should be able to find it in my API account information.`
I have no idea what kind of key they need.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Go to this site https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ select your project or create a new project after that go to "credentials" there you can find "key" ..

Answer (score 0):

Google API key is the key for authenticating the user while accessing the google services. For example, You can get API key for your's and using that key you can access to google Map service in your application

Comment: Okay thanks for the anwer. And how can I get this key?

Comment: Go to https://console.developers.google.com and create new project by clicking "create project"  near Google API's logo. Then click on credentials on side tab and you can find create credentials option and clicking that button create your API key. For this you have to sign in with your google account